# Soma do quadrado da regressão dos modelos R

Tags: r, script

Os modelos apresentados são diferentes em apenas um coeficiente adicional (f), que multiplica a variável independente (x), permitindo o cálculo do aumento da soma do quadrado da regressão, incluindo o coeficiente f com um valor diferente de zero. Desta forma é possível testar o quadrado médio associado à inclusão, com um grau da liberdade.

F=(SQmodeloBC.4-SQmodeloLL.3)/QMR

Quanto maior for valor deste quadrado médio, em relação ao quadrado médio do outro modelo, mais significativo é o ajuste do modelo, e a hipótese f=0 é rejeitada

Eu tenho a ideia porem não consigo realizar de forma "fácil e simples" no R. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#pacote curva dose resposta
library("drc")
#dose resposta "hormesis" modelo BC.4 = f(x) = 0 + \frac{d-0+fx}{1+\exp(b(\log(x)-\log(e)))}
lett.BC4 <- drm(weight ~ conc, data = lettuce, fct = BC.4())
#dose resposta "comum" modelo LL.3 = f(x) = 0 + \frac{d-0}{1+\exp(b(\log(x)-\log(e)))}
lett.LL3 <- drm(weight ~ conc, data = lettuce, fct = LL.3())  

plot(lett.BC4, col = 2, lty = 2)
plot(lett.LL3, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez, aqui mesmos no Stack Overflow, comentei sobre seleção de variáveis ([link para a publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276180/variaveis-selecionadas-no-glm-sendo-utilizadas-na-glmm/276236#276236)). O problema de seleção de variáveis é similar ao problema de seleção de modelos: estamos tentando escolher o modelo mais simples que explique nossos dados (em estatística, sempre desejamos o modelo mais simples possível para descrever nossos dados).

Mas para fazer um teste como este que tu deseja, com soma de quadrados, é necessário que os modelos testados sejam aninhados. O problema é que os teus modelos não são aninhados. Não faz sentido fazer um teste de hipóteses do tipo

- H_0: os modelos `lett.LL3` e `lett.BC4` são iguais
- H_1: os modelos `lett.LL3` e `lett.BC4` não são iguais

porque eles não são versões mais complexa e mais simples do mesmo modelo. As funções não-lineares definidas pelos argumentos `fct = BC.4()` e `LL.3()` são diferentes. Portanto, do ponto de vista teórico na teoria de Modelos Não-Lineares (ver Bates e Watts, Nonlinear Regression Analysis (1988), pp 103-104), o teste que tu está tentando aplicar não faz sentido. Ele pode ser feito numericamente, pois é possível calcular as somas de quadrados para cada um dos modelos, mas um teste assim não possui respaldo teórico.

O que pode ser feito é comparar dois modelos aninhados. Por exemplo,

```
lett.BC5 <- drm(weight ~ conc, data = lettuce, fct = BC.5())
lett.BC4 <- drm(weight ~ conc, data = lettuce, fct = BC.4())
```

A única diferença entre as funções não-lineares especificada por `fct = BC.5()` e `fct = BC.4()` é que `BC.5()` possui um parâmetro a mais:

```
summary(lett.BC5)

Model fitted: Brain-Cousens (hormesis) (5 parms)

Parameter estimates:

              Estimate Std. Error t-value   p-value    
b:(Intercept) 1.502065   0.352231  4.2644  0.002097 ** 
c:(Intercept) 0.280173   0.248569  1.1271  0.288836    
d:(Intercept) 0.963030   0.078186 12.3171 6.164e-07 ***
e:(Intercept) 1.120457   0.612908  1.8281  0.100799    
f:(Intercept) 0.988182   0.776136  1.2732  0.234846    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error:

 0.1149117 (9 degrees of freedom)

summary(lett.BC4)

Model fitted: Brain-Cousens (hormesis) with lower limit fixed at 0 (4 parms)

Parameter estimates:

              Estimate Std. Error t-value   p-value    
b:(Intercept) 1.282812   0.049346 25.9964 1.632e-10 ***
d:(Intercept) 0.967302   0.077123 12.5423 1.926e-07 ***
e:(Intercept) 0.847633   0.436093  1.9437   0.08059 .  
f:(Intercept) 1.620703   0.979711  1.6543   0.12908    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error:

 0.1117922 (10 degrees of freedom)
```

Desta forma, é possível comparar os modelos `lett.BC5` e `lett.BC4` de acordo com suas somas de quadrados e o teste de hipóteses definido acima:

```
anova(lett.BC5, lett.BC4)
1st model
 fct:      BC.4()
2nd model
 fct:      BC.5()

ANOVA table

          ModelDf     RSS Df F value p value
1st model      10 0.12498                   
2nd model       9 0.11884  1  0.4644  0.5127
```

(veja mais informações em `?anova.drc`)

Como o p-valor foi maior do que 0,05, podemos dizer que os modelos não são diferentes entre si, optando desta forma pelo `lett.BC4`, que é mais simples.

---

Veja que não respondi a pergunta principal. Talvez teu interesse seja decidir entre comparar as famílias de funções `LL` e `BC` e decidir qual a melhor família de funções para ajustar aos teus dados. Infelizmente, não conheço nenhum método estatístico tipo um teste de hipóteses para resolver este problema. Te dou as duas seguintes sugestões a respeito de como decidir entre `LL` e `BC`:

1) Escolha o melhor modelo possível entre as famílias `LL` e `BC`, utilizando a metodologia acima. Com os melhores modelos de cada família escolhidos, analise os resíduos dois dois modelos encontrados e, baseado na análise de resíduos, veja qual modelo viola menos hipóteses.

2) Faça uma escolha consciente. Veja na literatura da tua área se os modelos com `LL` (log-logistic model) e `BC` (Brain-Cousens modified log-logistic) são os mais utilizados e por quê. Ou, como tu está fazendo um ajuste paramétrico dos dados, diga que vai usar alguma destas duas opções por causa da interpretabilidade delas ou porque teus dados tem comportamento que lembra alguma delas. Ou, ainda, teste alguma outra função, como a Weibull, porque talvez os teus resultados sejam ainda melhores.